# read xml in python with cases count in a subscript

Tags: python, xml

I'm still learning python and I got stuck reading this xml file. can somebody please help, thanks

```
<traitment>
    <person_1>
        <resp> 129</resp>
        <positions>
            <p>1 2 3</p>
            <p>4 5 7 </p>
            <p>2 1 8</p>
        </positions>
    </person_1>
    <person_2>
        <resp> 150</resp>
        <positions>
            <p>0 1 2</p>
            <p>4 0 5 </p>
            <p>1 2 4</p>
        </positions>
    </person_2>
    <person_3>
        <resp>89 129</resp>
        <positions>
            <p>1 4 5</p>
            <p>1 2 3</p>
            <p>6 8 9</p>
        </positions>
    </person_3>
</traitment>
```

the output should be 3 rows of the same person, person1, having the same resp 129 and 3 positions (p1,p2,p3).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code we can look at, to find out what is potentially wrong?

Comment: here is code,it's not creating a second row or third row for person's positions 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse("sample.xml")
root = tree.getroot() 

df_cols = ["person","positions", "resp"]
rows = []
for node in root:
    s_person=node.tag
    print(s_entry)
    s_coord = node.find(".//positions/p").text if node is not None else None
    print(s_coord)
    s_resp = node.find("resp").text if node is not None else None
    print(s_energy)
    rows.append({"person":s_person, "positions":s_coord, "resp": s_resp})
out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols)

Comment: Please add the code to the question. Code in comments is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will get you the data you want, but it would help to know what it is exactly that you want to achieve: in what format do you want the result, for what end purpose,...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

my_xml_tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = my_xml_tree.getroot()

persons_rows = []
for person_node in root:
    new_person = {}
    persons_rows.append(new_person)
    new_person['person'] = person_node.tag
    new_person['resp'] = person_node.find('resp').text
    new_person['positions'] = []
    for position in person_node.find('positions'):
        new_person['positions'].append(position.text)

for person in persons_rows:
    print(f"person: {person['person']}, resp: {person['resp']}, positions: {person['positions']}")
```

The above code results in the following output for your `sample.xml` file:

```
person: person_1, resp:  129, positions: ['1 2 3', '4 5 7 ', '2 1 8']
person: person_2, resp:  150, positions: ['0 1 2', '4 0 5 ', '1 2 4']
person: person_3, resp: 89 129, positions: ['1 4 5', '1 2 3', '6 8 9']
```

Comment: @Tracy: Philippe has made an effort here. If this answer does not help, you should explain why.